# Retaining Blank Lines on macOS bash column

Tags: bash, macos

A series of commands in a group `{ command1; command2; }` is piped to `column` on macOS.

I want to insert a headings row, so I tried `cat file.txt;` as the first command in the group. This file contains the heading text followed by a blank line. However, the output (which *does* contain the blank line when run without the pipe to `column`) has the blank line stripped by `column`.

I can't find a way to overcome `column`'s default behaviour, so can I either insert the empty row after `column` or is there another utility that will generate columnar output without suppressing empty rows?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave this here in case it helps someone else:

For the sake of clarity, I omitted to mention that there is a blank line before the headings in the text file (so that the output is visually separated from preceding text).

I decided to pipe the column output to `sed`, then use `i` [insert] and `a` [append].  (I also added a blank line at the end using `$` and `a`.):

```
| sed '1i\

1a\

$a\

'
```